# TableView didSelect respond issue in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView running in my project successfully.But,I have a problem selecting cell and updating my textView which connected to tableview in the same viewController.My textView only updating when i do a long press on tableViewCell.I want to update textView everytime when cell been pressed.I believe,when i pressed the cell deselect itself. My partial code as follow..

Note:
I am using the below code in my different projects that works with no issue..I am not sure whats wrong with this tableview....

Thanks in Advance....

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let CellIdentifier: String = "fontCell"
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

     let fontName: String = self.fontName[indexPath.row] as! String

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in 

    cell.textLabel?.text = fontName
    cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName[indexPath.row] as! String, size: 25)

    }, completion: nil)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.selectionStyle = .Default

    return cell 
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  //tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    let fontName: String = self.fontName[indexPath.row] as! String

    self.textView.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 20)
  })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should already be called on the main thread so removing the `dispatch_async` and just running the code like this should be fine

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let fontName: String = self.fontName[indexPath.row] as! String
    self.textView.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 20)
}
```

If you've added a gesture recognizer to your tableView to handle long press (or something else) that might be interfering with your other taps. 
try setting cancelsTouchesInView to false on your recogniser.

```
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: Thanks Moriya. I already tried your solution.but no luck thats why i tried dispatch_async. I believe something wrong with my tableview controller physical setting that idont know yet...

Comment: Does the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath run? if you set a breakpoint in it does it stop when you select a row?

Comment: Thanks. Code works fine when i keep pressing the cell/ long press. But, when i press the cell the cell selected happening and as soon as lift the finger cell selected disappears and not updating the dest view... and i cant see any breakpoint in the code...

Comment: Thanks,Your updated code make more sense. In my viewController. i am using tap gesture function to dismiss keyboard in mainviewController . as soon as i change that piece of code everything works good....thanks